# Is there a super close substitute for graham crackers?

Tags: substitutions, graham-crackers

I'm from Canada (where there are multitudes of graham crackers!), but I'm currently living in Australia. They do not have anything like graham crackers here, and I could really use them for a couple recipes I'm developing.

Does anyone have a close substitute for graham crackers? I'm looking at making my own, but that seems like a tedious task just to crumble them up again.

Comment: Are you making a crumb crust? There are choices for crumb crusts that I find superior to graham crackers.

Comment: You can probably find 'digestive biscuits' in Australia. They are the ex British Empire's go-to for crumb crusts.

Comment: A dry/crunchy shortbread may work as well.

Comment: some of the crunchier gingersnaps might work too

Comment: [Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/Crackers.html) recommends 'wheatmeal biscuits' for Australians.  (or digestive biscuits (for Brits), gingersnaps, chocolate wafers or vanilla wafers)

Comment: Post answers, not comments! I'm taking the reputation y'all could've had.

Comment: Are you looking to substitute for real graham crackers (i.e. semi-sweet whole wheat crackers) or the Honey Maid type (part whole wheat, heavily sweetened)?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did end up going with the digestive biscuits. They didn't taste exactly the same, but they were certainly close enough in consistency!

Comment: You can order them online from Zoxoro Australia. This company appears to cater to commercial kitchens so is only available in bulk. The brand is called honey maid graham crackers. At a cost of $42.99 you get four 14 ounce boxes so you could go in with a friend to purchase them. I found them when I pressed the shopping tab on google.

Comment: Graham Norton is even sweeter than a graham cracker, although not quite as crunchy.  Add a pinch of salt to taste. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, try digestive biscuits. They're really very similar cookies/crackers/biscuits, and it's a common enough substitution that it's even [mentioned on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digestive_biscuit#Recipe_substitution). [Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/Crackers.html) implies that they're called wheatmeal biscuits in Australia.

sourd'oh's suggestion of particularly crunchy gingersnaps might work too, but you'll also want to make sure they're not too spicy!

(Unfortunately, I don't know about specific varieties since I'm not Australian.)

Answer (score 9):

I was in Australia last winter & discovered they don't sell any kind of graham wafer.  I substituted the digestive cookies/biscuits and found they are not as sweet.  Although the crust tasted good, the next time I made the 'graham wafer' crust, I added a teaspoon of sugar to the digestive biscuit crumbs ...now it tasted closer to the graham wafer crust I was used to.

Answer (score 7):

I am an Aussie. We use Marie biscuits.

Answer (score 5):

I use Grahams Crackers in my Key Lime pies.  The Key Limes are specific to Florida and I bring it back with me as a juice concentrate from Publix Supermarket.

I also bring back Grahams Crackers.  But when I run short there is ONLY ONE substitute in Australia. It's ARNOTT'S GRANITA.  You can get it at any Australian supermarket.

Have done a blind taste test with my friends and family to see if they can taste the difference between Granita and Grahams.  They can't.  I give them three pieces of granita and two pieces of Graham selected randomly while they are blindfolded.  NO ONE can pick the difference correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you live, some grocer shops have an international food section. But for a crunchy sweet pie crust, I don't think you can go past a **butternut snap biscuit**, sold just about anywhere in Australia. I have also used Milk Arrowroot or Morning Coffee. I like these too, but they aren't as sweet.

Comment: As an American, I've never even heard of a "butternut biscuit" let alone seen one... What do you mean by "sold just about anywhere"? Where is "anywhere"? And what is "milk arrowroot" and "morning coffee"... I've never heard of them, either.

Comment: The question was about availability of graham cracker substitutes in Australia. It seems that all three types, "Butternut snap biscuits", "Arrowroot milk biscuits" and "Morning coffee biscuits" are brand name bisquits produced by Arnott's, Australia's largest producer of biscuits/cookies.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Filipino groceries.  They stock Graham biscuits.  I've just bought some at Manila Mart in Ryde (Sydney) and have also seen them at Ashfield Mall in Sydney where the fruit and veg shop is run by Filipinos.

Answer (score 3):

I live in Australia and use Granita biscuits, mixed with 2 tablespoons of sugar, and 1/4 Cup of almond meal for my substitute to Graham crackers. All crushed together of course :)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that digesive or the suggested alternative Graham crackers would be the same as Arnott's wheatgerm biscuits or why not just use Arnott's  morning coffee or milk arrowroot.  I'm going to try the wheatgerm and see how that works.  Most biscuit bases could use any of these three suggestions in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Rich Tea biscuits if you find them. They are plain and they go perfect with any kind of cake

Answer (score 0):

I use digestive biscuits and add cinnamon to get them closer to the taste of Graham Crackers.

Answer (score -1):

I would look around the local grocer. There are many other graham products like Golden Grahams cereal, Teddy Graham snacks for kids and Annies Graham snacks, found in the organic section. Maybe you can find graham cracker crumbs in the baking section

Comment: I've never had these (wrong part of the world), but they don't sound like a good substitute. Basically, the OP needs a different kind of a dry cookie, not any product with "graham" in the name - especially the cereal sounds suspect. Also, are these products really available in Australia when standard graham crackers are not?

Comment: I'd be shocked if they were available if actual Graham crackers are not, but they'd actually possibly be valid substitutes as they're mostly just Graham cracker in bite sized form. (perhaps with more sugar and added flavouring (eg: chocolate, honey, cinnamon, etc...)

Comment: Even if he can find them, if I remember correctly Teddy Grahams and Golden Grahams are glazed with some sort of sugar coating that would make them a poor substitute.

Comment: FYI, we do not have Graham crackers in Belgium, but we do have Golden Grahams cereal.

Answer (score -1):

Best substitute is digestive biscuits (sweeter and crunchier than wholemeal) look for Mcvities brand they are Scottish  but available in Australia in Coles suoernarkets and other places. I use them all the time. They are great.

Comment: Please do not add the same answer as already given before - if you agree with an answer, simply vote it up.

Comment: @Divi McVitie's are Scottish, not English.  [See here](https://www.businessinsider.com/difference-between-great-britain-united-kingdom-england-scotland-wales-northern-ireland-republic-2017-4) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McVitie%27s)

Answer (score -2):

I think Arnotts Lattice biscuits might work well in this recipe. I will try it anyway