# Digestive cookies - substitute in South Africa?

Tags: substitutions

What is a good substitute for UK-style 'digestive cookies' in South Africa? It's for a crumb crust for a [chocolate mousse cake](http://twistedfood.co.uk/triple-chocolate-mocha-mousse-cake/).

Comment: What's the application? Are you serving them with something or using them in a recipe? If it's a recipe it would help if you could post it.

Comment: What 'digestive cookies' are your refering to? Those sold in the US?

Comment: http://twistedfood.co.uk/triple-chocolate-mocha-mousse-cake/

Comment: link to the recipe

Comment: related: graham cracker substitutes https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/50371/1672

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably get away with any kind of sweet hard biscuit.

I'm not South African, so I can't help you if you want a local biscuit, but looking at [Woolworth's](http://www.woolworths.co.za/store/) online shop suggests you might actually be able to find Digestives, or there's Bourbons, Shortbread, or even Ginger Nuts if you fancy trying something a little different from the recipe.

Note that although the recipe calls them cookies, it's just using the American term for biscuit (even though it seems to be a British website).